# How to mount FTP resources with fstab when connection is available?

Tags: fstab, automount, ftp, rsync, curlftpfs

I'd like to automount an FTP folder using `curlftpfs` putting in `fstab` a row like:

```
curlftpfs#user:pwd@myhost:port/folder/ /mnt/mymountfolder fuse allow_other,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=0022,_netdev 0 0
```

Normally it wouldn't work, as during the boot the network (wifi usually) is not available for my laptop. I read that `_netdev` option in fstab should ensure the mounting only when the network is available, but I receive the message:

```
Error connecting to ftp: Couldn't resolve host myhost
```

Alternatively I could mount the resource with an autorun script after the login has been made, but I'd like much more the fstab solution.

The final goal is to syncronize a local folder with the ftp folder with a crontab rsync, so if you have other suggestions, I will be grateful!

Comment: Looks like during boot the system was not able to resolve to `myhost`. You can add a IP <=> name mapping in `/etc/hosts`, see if it helps. Otherwise change myhost to FQDN or IP address.

Comment: myhost is a dynamic host provided by a service such as no-ip.org or ddns.com. It's pretty unuseful to substitute it with an IP...

Comment: Ok,is your system able to resolve to `myhost`? For example, do I ping and see if you can reach it. If not, you may have to do a IP - Hostname mapping in `/etc/hosts` to make it work.

Comment: Please explain me why don't you use **autofs**?

Comment: Sure, I can resolve myhost! For the mapping, as already said in the previous comment, is unuseful as it's dynamic host!

Autofs is quite difficult to configure, and I'm not sure it would solve the issue, as I'm investigating and I found my wireless is available only after the login. Both fstab and autofs solutions are near to be abandoned...:(

Comment: Does ist work when your network is up (`sudo mount -a`)? If not, can you try another server, e.g. ftp.mozilla.org? Also, I'm not sure if it's possible to add the `/folder/`-part in fstab.

Comment: Have you tried noauto switch? you can put it in place of _netdev

Comment: Six years after you posted this question I'm thinking cron@reboot to sleep 120 seconds, `mount` ftp on android phone, do some stuff and `umount` should work. Wondering if your experience over the years will confirm strategy?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As your goal is "to syncronize a local folder with the ftp folder with a crontab rsync", I suggest you to write a small script that mounts the FTP, rsync, unmount FTP. Then run this script from crontab.

It should go something like this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
curlftpfs user:pwd@myhost:port/folder/ /mnt/mymountfolder
#might need sleep 1 here
rsync -a /mnt/mymountfolder /local/folder
fusermount -uz /mnt/mymountfolder
```

Make sure you chmod +x on the script.

crontab -e

```bsh
#m h d M wd
0 * * * * /usr/local/bin/backup-script
```

Also, if you really want the FTP folder mounted all the time, you could make a script that mounts/unmounts your drive. If you also add it to fstab, you could manually mount the drive.

fstab:

```bsh
curlftpfs#user:pwd@myhost:port/folder/ /mnt/mymountfolder fuse noauto,user,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=0022 0 0
```

network-mount.sh:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
folder=/media/ftp
# check if host is alive
ping=`/usr/bin/fping -q host.dyn.org`
if [ $? == 0 ]; then
  # check if folder is mounted
  mountpoint $folder > /dev/null
  if [ $? != 0 ]
    # mount, timeout in case something goes wrong
    then timeout 10s mount $folder
  fi
  else
  mountpoint $folder > /dev/null
  if [ $? = 0 ]
    #unmount lazy (network down)
    then umount -l $folder
  fi
fi
```

Add this to crontab (crontab -e):

```bsh
* * * * * /usr/local/bin/network-mount.sh
```

Also watch out for your rsync not completing before the next is run. This could be done automatically(check if rsync running), or based upon how much data that need to be in sync(amount of time rsync takes, worst case scenario).

Assuming you don't run rsync for anything else, checking if it's running could be done like this:

```bsh
pgrep rsync
if [ $? == 0 ]; then
  # rsync running
  exit
else
  # rsync not running
  #do stuff
fi
```

Comment: Yes, it works. The folder is correctly mounted, but rsync isn't copying anything.

Comment: Try adding verbose to rsync, to check whats going on. "rsync -av /media/ftp /local/folder"

Comment: it's a simple "operation not permitted". Note that a cp works!

Comment: Do you have write permission on the destination folder? ls -ld /local/folder. Are you able to browse and open files on mounted folder? What brand is your NAS? Most NAS today support more modern protocol than FTP.

Comment: I wrote that cp works, so I have permissions to write!

Comment: Sorry, didn't catch that. Is it the script or rsync that gives you the error message?

Comment: rsync, I tried the single commands first.

Comment: -a is equivalent to -rlptgoD, so it could be a number of things. For example rsync tries to preserve owner, which may fail if your not privileged to do so. Try running it as root: `sudo rsync ...` Without any more then, "operation not permitted", I'm not sure what it could be. Also note that rsync still copies the files in many cases where you get an error message.

Comment: Good answer. But consider putting your password in the `/root/.netrc` file. https://linuxconfig.org/mount-remote-ftp-directory-host-locally-into-linux-filesystem

Answer (score 0):

I'm using SFTP / sshfs for that purpose

```
echo password | sshfs username@serverIP:/ /mnt/mountpointfolder -p portnumber -o reconnect -o password_stdin
```

Not sure if there is a fstab way. If you execute a cron job doing this every x minutes, would be ok. If the folder is already mounted, you will just get "already connected" error. If you are disconnected, you will get another error and no connection will be made. But when you are connected again, you will connect in a minute... In case of cron job you can remove `-o reconnect` part.

Make the script file secure as it contain the password.

Comment: If only my NAS could handle ssh...!

Comment: it does not? OMG! Dummy NASes. Who could use FTP unsecured?

Answer (score 0):

You may try curlftpfs option

> connect_timeout=N (seconds).

In your example (let us say 30 secs are enough),

> curlftpfs#user:pwd@myhost:port/folder/ /mnt/mymountfolder,  uid=1000, gid=1000, umask=0022, connect_timeout=30 0 0 fuse -o allow_other

Alternatively, you can remove from fstab and connect in Nautilus, then save it as bookmark and connect each time you startup.