# CLI path to ftp network connection

Tags: command-line, ftp, filemanager

I've setup a connectio to an FTP server in Nautilus / Nemo / Caja, the file manager. Now I can browse the contents via this file manager.

How can I browse these files via the command line? What is the path to this network connection? Is this possible, is this a system connection, or specific to the file manager, and do I have to setup a separate FTP connection to do that? If I open this connection in Caja, I see it in Nemo as well, so it seems like a system connection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The location you are looking for is: `/run/user/1000/gvfs`. Or more precisely `/run/user/$UID/gvfs`. 
The approach that I've used to get this is shown on the following animation.

[image: The approach, that I used to get path /run/user/1000/gvfs]

---

You can use also the option `Open in Local Terminal` from the context menu (right mouse button):

[image]

---

**The initial answer:**

This is not exact answer of your question, but it may be useful. You can mount FTP instance into your file system via the tool `curlftpfs`:

```
sudo apt install curlftpfs
sudo mkdir /mnt/ftp
sudo chown $USER:$USER /mnt/ftp

curlftpfs user:password@host:port/folder/ /mnt/ftp/
```

You can make script or `fstab` entry to automate the mounting process, as it is described [**here**](https://askubuntu.com/a/323215/566421).

According to your original question, as it is described [**here**](https://askubuntu.com/a/871389/566421), you can mount and SSH instance.

Comment: File-path drag-and-drop works for SMB/CIFS share too. It seems it solves [my recent question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966670/how-to-open-gvfs-smb-cifs-mount-location-in-terminal-from-caja). Thank you!

Comment: @N0rbert, I will flag your question as duplication, then you could accept it.