# How to open gvfs SMB/CIFS mount location in terminal from Caja?

Tags: 16.04, mount, smb, gvfs, caja

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS with MATE DE.
I have Samba server in my network (its name is `server`, share is `share`).

I open Caja 1.12.7 file-manager and put `smb://server/share` to *Location*. I have `caja-open-terminal` installed.

In previous Ubuntu versions such as Ubuntu 12.04 LTS I was able to open terminal from Caja when it shows contents of `smb://server/share`.
Terminal was opened inside `~/.gvfs/share on server/` folder. I was able to start for example Midnight Commander (`mc`) here.

How I can open terminal in such SMB locations in Ubuntu 16.04 from Caja?

*Note*: I understand that I can navigate to

```
/run/user/`id -u`/gvfs/smb-share
```

manually. But this solution is not user-friendly.

Comment: The solution is located [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/876425/66509). User can use drag-and-drop location to the terminal.