# Mounted SFTP with Dolphin, how to access from command line?

Tags: kubuntu, sftp, dolphin

I have mounted an SFTP share using Dolphin, which all works perfectly. However, I would also like to browse these files from the command line.

Pressing F4 in Dolphin to bring up a terminal window just gives me my home directory, and not the remote one.
I cannot see the remote mount when running `mount`.

Is there a way to `cd` to the SFTP after mounting it in Dolphin, like I could if I had mounted it with `sshfs`?

Nautilus uses gvfs to mount remote shares, which makes life easier, as shown [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/876398). However, that does not seem to be the case with Dolphin (Kubuntu). I don't have anything in `/run/user/$UID/gfvs/` after mounting my SFTP share in Dolphin.

Comment: No, I don't think so, unfortunately. The above post is about Nautilus, and not Dolphin. In Dolphin/Kubuntu, I don't have anything in `/run/user/$UID/gvfs` and it appears that Dolphin is not using gvfs.

Comment: I see, Dolphin uses KIO instead of GVFS which seems not to "physically" mount, but just provides a layer of access. That would mean you cannot access it from terminal. [Read here](https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/525765-How-to-access-dolphin-network-mount-through-console).

Comment: As @pLumo mentioned, dolphin does not mount the share. If a share is mounted it behaves like a local location. If you mount the share manually by following e.g. this https://blog.mehl.mx/2014/mounting-a-sftp-storage-in-gnu-linux/  excelent guide, you will also be able to access the remote share on the command line.

Comment: OK, I see. Stupid dolphin :-/ With `kioclient5 ls` as in the OpenSUSE link above, I can list contents from the command line, but unfortunately there is no `kioclient5 cd` command, so I can't run scripts on the remote files etc. So I guess I really do have to use `sshfs` instead.

Comment: This is disappointing. What's the advantage of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

With Dolphin i dont found solution. But i have installed `nautilus` and `gvfs-fuse` and commented  the line `Environment=GVFS_DISABLE_FUSE=1` in the file `/lib/systemd/system/accounts-daemon.service` and run `systemctl daemon-reload` and restart the machine.
I have installed `nautilus-extension-gnome-terminal` too, to add "open in local terminal" to Nautilus context menu.

PS:Im using Kubuntu 20.04.